# Octave: converting dataframe to cell array

Tags: dataframe, octave

Given an Octave dataframe object created as

```
c = cell(m,n);
%populate c...

pkg load dataframe
df = dataframe(c);
```

(see https://octave.sourceforge.io/dataframe/overview.html),

1. Is it possible to access the underlying cell array?
2. Is it there a conversion mechanism back to cell array?
3. Is it possible to save `df` to CSV?

Comment: man, what a hostile place so has become

Comment: meh, it's always been like that. you get used to it. welcome aboard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. A dataframe object, like any object, can be converted back into a `struct`.

Once you have the resulting struct, look for the fields `x_name` to get the column names, and `x_data` to get the data in the form of a cell array, i.e.

```
struct(df).x_data
```

As for conversion to csv, the dataframe package does not seem to provide any relevant methods as far as I can tell (in particular the package does not provide an overloaded `@dataframe/csvwrite` method). Therefore, I'd just extract the information as above, and go about writing it into a csv file from there.

If you're not dealing with strictly numerical data, you might want to have a look at the `cell2csv` / `csv2cell` methods from the `io` package (since the built-in `csvwrite` function is strictly for numerical data).
And if that doesn't do exactly what you want, I'd probably just go for creating a csv file manually via custom `fprintf` statements.

---

<sub>PS. You can generally see what methods a package provides via **pkg describe -verbose dataframe**, or the methods for a particular class via **methods(dataframe)** (or even **methods(df)**). Also, if you ever wanted to access the documentation for an overloaded method, e.g. say the **summary** method, then this is the syntax for doing so: **help @dataframe/summary**</sub>