# Dimension problem when converting a MATLAB .m script into an Octave compatible syntax

Tags: octave

I want to run a MATLAB script M-file to reconstruct a point cloud in Octave. Therefore I had to rewrite some parts of the code to make it compatible with Octave. Actually the M-file works fine in Octave (I don't get any errors) and also the plotted point cloud looks good at first glance, but it seems that the variables are only half the size of the original MATLAB variables. In the attached screenshots you can see what I mean.

Octave:

[image: Dimensions in Octave]

MATLAB:

[image: Dimensions in MATLAB]

You can see that the dimension of e.g. `M` in Octave is 1311114x3 but in MATLAB it is 2622227x3. The actual number of rows in my raw file is 2622227 as well.

Here you can see an extract of the raw file (original data) that I use.

```
Rotation angle  Measured distance
-0,090  26,295
-0,342  26,294
-0,594  26,294
-0,846  26,295
-1,098  26,294
-1,368  26,296
-1,620  26,296
-1,872  26,296
```

In MATLAB I created my output variable as follows.

```
data = table;
data.Rotationangle = cell2mat(raw(:, 1));
data.Measureddistance = cell2mat(raw(:, 2));
```

As there is no `table` function in Octave I wrote

```
data = cellfun(@(x)str2num(x), strrep(raw, ',', '.'))
```

instead.

Octave also has no `struct2array` function, so I had to replace it as well.
In MATLAB I wrote.

```
data = table2array(data);
```

In Octave this was a bit more difficult to do. I had to create a `struct2array` function, which I did by means of [this bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50622).

```
%% Create a struct2array function
function retval = struct2array (input_struct)
  %input check
  if (~isstruct (input_struct) || (nargin ~= 1))
    print_usage;
  endif

  %convert to cell array and flatten/concatenate output.
  retval = [ (struct2cell (input_struct)){:}];  
endfunction

clear b;
b.a = data;
data = struct2array(b);
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere and could someone help me to solve this problem?

**edit:**

Here's the part of my script where I'm using `raw`.

```
delimiter = '\t';
startRow = 5;
formatSpec = '%s%s%[^\n\r]';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r'); 
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
fclose(fileID);

%% Convert the contents of columns containing numeric text to numbers.
%  Replace non-numeric text with NaN.
raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
    raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = mat2cell(dataArray{col}, ones(length(dataArray{col}), 1));   
end

numericData = NaN(size(dataArray{1},1),size(dataArray,2)); 

for col=[1,2]
    % Converts text in the input cell array to numbers. Replaced non-numeric
    % text with NaN.
    rawData = dataArray{col};
    for row=1:size(rawData, 1)
        % Create a regular expression to detect and remove non-numeric prefixes and
        % suffixes.
        regexstr = '(?<prefix>.*?)(?<numbers>([-]*(\d+[\.]*)+[\,]{0,1}\d*[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1})|([-]*(\d+[\.]*)*[\,]{1,1}\d+[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1}))(?<suffix>.*)';
        try
            result = regexp(rawData(row), regexstr, 'names');
            numbers = result.numbers;

            % Detected commas in non-thousand locations.
            invalidThousandsSeparator = false;
            if numbers.contains('.')
                thousandsRegExp = '^\d+?(\.\d{3})*\,{0,1}\d*$';
                if isempty(regexp(numbers, thousandsRegExp, 'once'))
                    numbers = NaN;
                    invalidThousandsSeparator = true;
                end
            end

            % Convert numeric text to numbers.
            if ~invalidThousandsSeparator
                numbers = strrep(numbers, '.', '');
                numbers = strrep(numbers, ',', '.');
                numbers = textscan(char(numbers), '%f');
                numericData(row, col) = numbers{1};
                raw{row, col} = numbers{1};
            end
        catch
            raw{row, col} = rawData{row};
        end
    end
end
```

You don't see any `raw` in my workspaces because I clear all temporary variables before I reconstruct my point cloud.
Also my original data in row 1311114 and 1311115 look normal.

**edit 2:**

As suggested here is a small example table to clarify what I want and what MATLAB does with the `table2array` function in my case.

```
data =

   -0.0900   26.2950
   -0.3420   26.2940
   -0.5940   26.2940
   -0.8460   26.2950
   -1.0980   26.2940
   -1.3680   26.2960
   -1.6200   26.2960
   -1.8720   26.2960
```

With the `struct2array` function I used in Octave I get the following array.

```
data =

    -0.090000    26.295000
    -0.594000    26.294000
    -1.098000    26.294000
    -1.620000    26.296000
    -2.124000    26.295000
    -2.646000    26.293000
    -3.150000    26.294000
    -3.654000    26.294000
```

If you compare the Octave array with my original data, you can see that every second row is skipped. This seems to be the reason for 1311114 instead of 2622227 rows.

**edit 3:**

I tried to solve my problem with the suggestions of @Tasos Papastylianou, which unfortunately was not successful. 
First I did the variant with a struct.

```
data = struct();
data.Rotationangle = [raw(:,1)];
data.Measureddistance = [raw(:,2)];
data = cell2mat( struct2cell (data ).' )
```

But this leads to the following structure in my script. (Unfortunately the result is not what I would like to have as shown in edit 2. Don't be surprised, I only used a small part of my raw file to accelerate the run of my script, so here are only 769 lines.)

```
  [766,1] = -357,966
  [767,1] = -358,506
  [768,1] = -359,010
  [769,1] = -359,514
  [1,2] = 26,295
  [2,2] = 26,294
  [3,2] = 26,294
  [4,2] = 26,296
```

Furthermore I get the following error.

```
error: unary operator '-' not implemented for 'cell' operands
error: called from
    Cloud_reconstruction at line 137 column 11
```

Also the approach with the `dataframe` octave package didn't work. When I run the following code it leads to the error you can see below.

```
dataframe2array = @(df) cell2mat( struct(df).x_data );
pkg load dataframe;
data = dataframe();
data.Rotationangle = [raw(:, 1)];
data.Measureddistance = [raw(:, 2)];
dataframe2array(data)
```

error:

```
warning: Trying to overwrite colum names
warning: called from
    df_matassign at line 147 column 13
    subsasgn at line 172 column 14
    Cloud_reconstruction at line 106 column 20
warning: Trying to overwrite colum names
warning: called from
    df_matassign at line 176 column 13
    subsasgn at line 172 column 14
    Cloud_reconstruction at line 106 column 20
warning: Trying to overwrite colum names
warning: called from
    df_matassign at line 147 column 13
    subsasgn at line 172 column 14
    Cloud_reconstruction at line 107 column 23
warning: Trying to overwrite colum names
warning: called from
    df_matassign at line 176 column 13
    subsasgn at line 172 column 14
    Cloud_reconstruction at line 107 column 23
error: RHS(_,2): but RHS has size 768x1
error: called from
    df_matassign at line 179 column 11
    subsasgn at line 172 column 14
    Cloud_reconstruction at line 107 column 23
```

Both error messages refer to the following part of my script where I'm doing the reconstruction of the point cloud in cylindrical coordinates.

```
distLaserCenter = 47; % Distance between the pipe centerline and the blind zone in mm
m = size(data,1);   % Find the length of the first dimension of data
zincr = 0.4/360;   % z increment in mm per deg
data(:,1) = -data(:,1);    

for i = 1:m    
    data(i,2) = data(i,2) + distLaserCenter;    
    if i == 1 
        data(i,3) = 0;
    elseif abs(data(i,1)-data(i-1)) < 100
        data(i,3) = data(i-1,3) + zincr*(data(i,1)-data(i-1));
    else abs(data(i,1)-data(i-1)) > 100;
        data(i,3) = data(i-1,3) + zincr*(data(i,1)-(data(i-1)-360));
    end
end
```

To give some background information for a better understanding. The script is used to reconstruct a pipe as a point cloud. The surface of the pipe was scanned from inside with a laser and the laser measured several points (distance from laser to the inner wall of the pipe) at each deg of rotation. I hope this helps to understand what I want to do with my script.

Comment: Please provide the whole (relevant part of the) script you use. I don't see any `raw` in your workspaces. What does your original data look like in row 1311114 and 1311115? Is there any corrupt data, where Octave maybe behaves differently than MATLAB? I assume, the error arises early in your code and is data related, and I guess, all of the struct stuff is irrelevant here.

Comment: @UsmanKhan: Please don't format program names as code.

Comment: Your code is not complete. Please see [mre]. What are `formatSpec` and `delimiter` in the call to `textscan`? --- I think using `'\r\n'` as line ending is problematic. Instead, open your file in `'rt'` mode. The `'t'` indicates "text mode", and on Windows silently replaces the `\r\n` with `\n`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you for your guidance. I will take care of it in future edits.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sorry for that, I added the missing code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo When I use `'rt'` instead of `'\r\n'` I get the following error: `textscan: EndOfLine must be at most one character or '\r\n'`.

Comment: @Marc I don't think your struct2array function does what you want it to do (that `{:}` bit presumably makes the whole thing a single row array, which is unlikely to be what you're after, right?). Try it on a small example table so you can check for yourself. Better yet, make a small example table here with expected and actual octave / matlab outputs, so we can help you using concrete code, rather than having to assume and imagine what you have and what you need (this is partly what Cris means by "minimal reproducible example" )

Comment: I meant to open the file in text mode. Use `fopen(filename,'rt');`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but here's a toy example of how a struct could be used in an equivalent manner to a table:

matlab:

```
data = table;
data.A = [1;2;3;4;5];
data.B = [10;20;30;40;50];
table2array(data)
```

octave:

```
data = struct();
data.A = [1;2;3;4;5];
data.B = [10;20;30;40;50];
cell2mat( struct2cell (data ).' )
```

Note the transposition operation (`.'`) before passing the result to `cell2mat`, since in a table, the 'fieldnames' are arranged horizontally in columns, whereas the struct2cell ends up arranging what used to be the 'fieldnames' as rows.

---

You might also be interested in the `dataframe` octave package, which performs similar functions to matlab's table (or in fact, R's dataframe object): https://octave.sourceforge.io/dataframe/  (you can install this by typing `pkg install -forge dataframe` in your console)

Unfortunately, the way to display the data as an array is still not ideal (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55417141/4183191), but you can easily convert that into a tiny function, e.g.

```
dataframe2array = @(df) cell2mat( struct(df).x_data );
```

Your code can then become:

```
pkg load dataframe;
data = dataframe();
data.A = [1;2;3;4;5];
data.B = [10;20;30;40;50];
dataframe2array(data)
```

Comment: I have tried to solve my problem with your approaches, which I did not manage unfortunately because other errors occurred. You can see more details in my initial question under edit 3.

Comment: Hi @Marc. Alas, your problem is unsolvable, since it's probably something you're doing wrong. It seems unlikely to be related to tables, textscans, or concatenations, and more likely that you're setting up your data wrong. Unfortunately in the absence of something we can copy paste and test on a PC, there's nothing we can do (and, no, copy pasting your entire code is inappropriate). You already have 3-questions-in-1 here, and none of them has a minimal example; even attempting an answer would come down to guesswork and speculation, so I would say this question is pretty much unsalvageable.

Comment: @Marc My advice would be to study your problem and come up with a minimal example for each question you need to ask. Chances are you'll solve your problem while trying to come up with the minimal example anyway, as is often the case. Furthermore, octave has excellent debugging facilities. Use them to go through your code step by step and figure out WHERE the problem occurs, and what your data and variables are doing at the time. Finally have a look at https://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html, http://xyproblem.info/, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example etc

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I try to detect the problem and find a minimal example.